# Remove Word from Paragraph Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove a word from a paragraph using javascript. So far I've written this, but no luck with having it remove the word.

The word I'm trying to remove is **S\n\nSubheadline space\n\n**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( 'S\n\nSubheadline space\n\n', "");
});
```

```html
  <p><span class="excerpt_part"><strong>HANDRAIL</strong>S\n\nSubheadline space\n\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis…</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems:

- You're not invoking the function properly (you aren't using jQuery anywhere either - I'd just remove that part entirely)
- The `innerHTML` does not contain *literal newlines*, but *backslash characters* followed by `n`:

```js
const spanText = document.querySelector('span').innerHTML;
console.log(spanText);
console.log(spanText.length);
```

```html
<span>\n</span>
```

The behavior of `\n` is not the same in JS (where the backslash is an escape character) as it is in HTML markup (where the backslash is not an escape character).

So you need to match a literal backslash followed by an `n`, which requires writing out two backslashes in a JS string literal:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( 'S\\n\\nSubheadline space\\n\\n', "");
```

```html
<p><span class="excerpt_part"><strong>HANDRAIL</strong>S\n\nSubheadline space\n\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis…</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the newline chars with an extra backslash.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('S\\n\\nSubheadline space\\n\\n', "")
```

```html
<p><span class="excerpt_part"><strong>HANDRAIL</strong>S\n\nSubheadline space\n\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis…</span></p>
```